# UIView's convertRect:fromView: returning a larger rect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In a `<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>` object, I am trying to convert a rect from one coordinate system to another.

When I call convertRect:fromView: however, I seem to be getting back a strange value -- the origin looks correct, but the dimensions of my rect have doubled.

Here is my code

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(fromViewController.view.bounds.size, YES, 0);
    [fromViewController.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:fromViewController.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    image = [image applyLightEffect];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIView *container = [UIView new];
    container.frame = endFrame;
    container.clipsToBounds = YES;
    UIImageView *imgView = [UIImageView new];
    imgView.image = image;
    //fromViewController.view's frame is printing out as: frame = (0 0; 320 568);
    imgView.frame = [container convertRect:fromViewController.view.frame fromView:transitionContext.containerView];
    //imgView.frame is printing out as: frame = (-40 -60; 640 1136)
    [container addSubview:imgView];
```

Am I missing something? Why would the rect grow??

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the from view controller's frame should already be in the container view's coordinate system, so you probably don't need this step.